# Android Gallery view with images saved in sqlite as blob

Tags: java, android

i need to show images from sqlite database into gridview or gallery view.
this is the code for displaying on a single view:

```
mMain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMain);
byte[] blob = imgs.getBytes(); //there is a method that will return the bytes from the database
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
mMain.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

i have the android tutorial for grid view but it gets the image from file

```
// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3
... }
```

is there a way to populate the gridview from the sqlite database?

**UPDATE:**
Im using the ImageAdapter provide in android tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
my code becomes this:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> image_arr = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
//loop through all images on sqlite
for(int l = 0 ;l< db.getAllImages().size(); l++){
    Image imgs = db.getAllImages().get(l); 
    byte[] blob = imgs.getBytes();  
    image_arr.add(blob);

    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
   // mMain.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
//TODO; find way to make the bitmap get to the ImageView

Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

This code is on main activity so i need to find way to pass the resources in ImageView which is in other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void getDataAndPopulate() {

    image = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    caption = new ArrayList<String>();

    cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from NAME",null);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(2);
        String temp_caption = cursor.getString(1);
        String temp_id= cursor.getString(0);
        image.add(temp_image);
        caption.add(temp_caption);
        id.add(temp_id);
    }
    String[] captionArray = (String[]) caption.toArray(
            new String[caption.size()]);

    ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(Item_show_grid.this, R.layout.item_grid,captionArray);
    gv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast! i'll check right away. thank you for feedback

Comment: thank you @aashutosh, ArrayList<byte[]> image = new ArrayList<byte[]>(); idea help me handling an array of bytes, this will pass to ItemsAdapter, but please explain more of this ItemsAdapter i'm currently using the sample adapter: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html